# Изменить цвет панели видеоролика youtube

Tags: javascript, youtube, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно изменить цвет панели при проигрывании видеоролика с `youtube` через `fancybox`. По умолчанию она серая, а хотелось бы чёрную.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Искали? Я да, и нашел: [Параметры встроенного проигрывателя YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=ru).

Comment: я это пробовал, не помогает. там в самом низу они привели пример плеера с голубой панелью. как видите, она по прежнему серая

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin  http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?color1=0x2b405b&color2=0x6b8ab6&fs=1 у меня синяя.

Comment: как странно. по вашей ссылке зашёл  - панель чёрно-серая. несколько раз обновил страницу, цвет тот же остался. но когда поставил курсор в адресную строку и нажал энтер, то  панель стала синяя.

повторил эту последовательность действий несколько раз, результат тот же

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin у меня также :-) Не знаю, но кроме офф. документации не нашел ничего больше интересного.